# TSQL merge fails for for identity column even if code is not run through

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I've written an application which creates T-SQL code to merge data from one database to another. The structure in of both databases are equal.

My generated code fails if the table I want insert to has an autoincrement column.

I solved it temporarily like this: if the table contains no autoincrement column, I just merge it. Else I move the data from the target table, insert the new one and just recreate the missing from a buffer of the old table.

```
  IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [TargetDB].[dbo].syscolumns
        WHERE id = Object_ID('[TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable]')
            AND colstat & 1 = 1
        )
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable] ON
END

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [TargetDB].[dbo].syscolumns
        WHERE id = Object_ID('[TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable]')
            AND colstat & 1 = 1
        )
BEGIN
print 'Path1'
    SELECT *
    INTO [TargetDB].[dbo].[SourceTable_Copy]
    FROM [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable]

    TRUNCATE TABLE [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable]

    INSERT INTO [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable] (
        [ID]
        ,[RecordID]
        ,[Another Info]
        )
    SELECT [ID]
        ,[RecordID]
    FROM [LinkedServer].[SourceDB].[dbo].[SourceTable]

    MERGE [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable] AS TR
    USING [TargetDB].[dbo].[SourceTable_Copy] AS SR
        ON ((TR.[ID] = SR.[ID]))
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                [ID]
                ,[RecordID]
                ,[Another Info]
                )
            VALUES (
                [ID]
                ,[RecordID]
                ,[Another Info]
                );

    DROP TABLE [TargetDB].[dbo].[SourceTable_Copy];
END
ELSE
BEGIN
print 'Path2'
    MERGE [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable] AS TR
    USING [LinkedServer].[SourceDB].[dbo].[SourceTable] AS SR
        ON ((TR.[ID] = SR.[ID]))
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN
            UPDATE
            SET TR.[RecordID] = SR.[RecordID]
                ,TR.[Another Info] = SR.[Another Info]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN
            INSERT (
                [ID]
                ,[RecordID]
                ,[Another Info]
                )
            VALUES (
                SR.[ID]
                ,SR.[RecordID]
                ,SR.[Another Info]
                );
END

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [TargetDB].[dbo].syscolumns
        WHERE id = Object_ID('[TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable]')
            AND colstat & 1 = 1
        )
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TargetDB].[dbo].[TargetTable] OFF
END
GO
```

My problem is that the code fails with this error:

> Msg 8102, Level 16, State 1, Line 64
>   Cannot update identity column 'Another Info'.

The error occurs even if the code is not run through. If I comment out the merge statement it returns "Path1".

Did anybody knows this problem and/or can provide a solution or some ideas?

**UPDATE:**
I edited the upper code and error message to indicate that the problem occurs on non primary key fields to.

Comment: You should use `sys.columns` instead of `dbo.syscolumns`

Comment: So you are trying to update identity column in conditions: `WHEN TR.[ID] = SR.[ID] UPDATE TR.[ID] = SR.[ID]`? Also note, `update` is not the same as `insert`.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: Yes im updating the identity column in the statement.
But the SQL Server should (and do) never run throu this code if there is a identity column in the table.

Comment: Please have another look on this code: `WHEN TR.[ID] = SR.[ID] UPDATE TR.[ID] = SR.[ID]`

Comment: @IvanStarostin: Thank you for repating. That was one of the problems. But the Error also occurs if the identity column is not in the primary key. That's what im driving at.

Comment: You can only set the value of a column marked as an identity if you use `SET IDENTITY INSERT [table_name] ON`